# Creating static database in Objective-C and make it searchable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating my very first app in Objective-C, which needs to contain static database in app itself. Idea is that even without internet connection user can use the database and search for the required info.

As I understood from what I read using Core Data and SQLite will not be very good in my case or I need to create a database separately and use it with Core Data or something like this.

Data in database will be only strings.

Can You please advise what will be the best way in my case?

Thanks

Comment: How much static data you have ? based on that we will suggest best way of storing static data.

Comment: I don't see a problem with using core data.

Comment: Quite a lot. It will be application related to health and e-additives. So there are around 700 e-additive names in total, and of course, there will be description of each additive (in each additive there will be 5 properties like additive name, possible effects to health...)

Comment: So whats the problem with Core Data or SQLite you can use any of them with your Static data.

Comment: 700 records with 5 properties is a very small data set and you could use any numbers of methods to store it and search it.  I would simply put it all in a json file, parse it into an array of dictionaries and deal with it only in memory.

Comment: I'd use coredata definitely. Though, I've used json before for static database. Either can work depends on your preference I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in using Core Data, or you can simply use a plist file to store your 700 e-additives.